# Search for word that may have hex characters

Tags: javascript, python, hex

I'm trying to use Python to search for the keyword "javascript" within a sentence, i.e.

```
data = "I am trying to search javascript in data"
```

But the problem in searching for "javascript" is that there might be some characters represented as their hex equivalents,
i.e.,
`javascript`, `Jav#61Script`, or `4A#61#76#61#53#63#72#69#70#74` and so on.

The whole word is might be represented as hex, or only part of it might be. So how can I properly search for `javascript`?

Comment: It would help to share any coding attempts you've made so far

Comment: I just wrote to search for keywords in pdf file using regular expression but the problem I found how to find a keyword that can be represented in hex

Comment: See my answer for a working implementation of Scott's advice.

Comment: sorry but I can't find it out, could you guide me to it?

Comment: [Uhh, sure?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23022237/2588818)

Comment: aha very sorry you mean the answer which is down, so if I have many words to search for them I have to do like this for each one ? is thattrue ?

Comment: No. The code I gave will work regardless of the number of words (as long as they are in the same string). `test_string` could be the text of Moby Dick for all it cares -- it just takes longer to run.

Comment: aha thats totally understood thank you very much. but there is something is missing to me, how could I know for example  "j#61v#61script" is in "I am searching for j#61v#61script here" ?

Comment: `'j#61v#61script' in 'I am searching for j#61v#61script here'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty. It's not efficient. But it works.

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'#[0-9A-F]+')
>>> 
>>> test_string = '#4A#61#76#61#53#63#72#69#70#74'
>>> for hex_string in re.findall(regex, test_string):
...   test_string = test_string.replace(hex_string, chr(int(hex_string.replace('#', ''), 16)))
... 
>>> test_string
'JavaScript'
```

There might be a better way if there is a library or something that handles this encoding scheme, but as it is I do not recognize it so I have nothing to recommend but "brute force".

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a regular expression, where each successive character can be either the letter (either case?) or it's hex representation.